# How to reload the editor in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode

In XCode 6, code completion will stop working for me often and I'll switch around a few files, until eventually the editor crashes and I get hit with a million errors.

Is there anyway I can manually reload the editor to recover code completion? It'd be nice if I could just hit a button and it would reload rather than waiting for it to crash itself.

Comment: This seems like a workaround -- if possible, you'd be better off eliminating the problem in the first place. Make sure your system is up to date, consider reinstalling Xcode, ask here about solutions to the problem rather than how to work around it.

Comment: I mean, I'm on the latest Xcode (beta) with the latest OSX with the latest updates. I'm not so sure I'm going to be able to eliminate the problem and really is it worth the huge loss of productivity probably associated with finding it? No thank you, something simple please I gotta get things done :)

Comment: Mentioning that you're using a beta version of Xcode (and mentioning the specific version) would've been helpful. I hope you've at least reported the bug.

Comment: I'll make a better question next time. No I haven't reported the bug. It's a beta and there's very little that's unique about my setup. Maybe I'm acting selfish, but I also am under a lot of pressure at my real job & pay my $99 dues. Sorry if I offended you. I just wanted to know if there was a simple way to reload the editor; clearly its constant crashes where it does reload itself shows there's *some* way to do it. Just wasn't sure if there was an interface available to users for to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to delete modulecache

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
```

Comment: This trick is super effective, been using it past few hours. works like a charm everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you want, but you can open a new tab via Cmd+t which opens a fresh editor window with the exact same file you were working with.